# Replace view in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a view (Let's say 'ViewA') and I want to replace it, what supporting syntax do we have? I went through the documentation, maybe not thoroughly enough, and found nothing.

I got this: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html#syntax

But this is of little help.

These are the commands I am using:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name (alias_1, alias_2) AS
 SELECT col_1, col_2
 FROM table
 WHERE col_3 > 2;


 alter VIEW view_name (alias_1, alias_2) AS
 SELECT col_1 as 'Employee Name', 
 col_2 as 'alias_3'
 FROM table
 WHERE col_3 > 2;
```

Comment: Drop it and create a new view.

Comment: i did, but still I am not able to replace it. I am eager to know it's syntax for future use. This is the error I'm getting -> 'SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 1 unexpected 'REPLACE'.'

Comment: There is no such alter view functionality.

Comment: Can you post the command as you are writing it?

Comment: In doc you cited, you can read: ALTER VIEW

Modifies the properties for an existing view. Currently the only supported operations are renaming a view, converting/reverting a secure view, and adding/overwriting/removing a comment for a view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax, documented on the page you linked. Example:

```
create or replace VIEW view_name (alias_1, alias_2) AS
SELECT col_1 as 'Employee Name', 
col_2 as 'alias_3'
FROM table
WHERE col_3 > 2
```

This should be an atomic operation.

If this is not what you're looking for, please explain what you mean by "replace" exactly.

Comment: Yes! I just noticed that. Funny why one needs to write 'create or replace' when simply writing 'replace' would do the job (if it had been made that way). Maybe to eliminate that rare case when a VIEW is not created and someone want to replace it. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: In principle you're right, but it's pretty rare people want to REPLACE things explicitly. The main reason for CREATE OR REPLACE is a situation when one doesn't know if a given object exists. If it does, CREATE would fail.